# Difference between namespace and use especially in php laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

What's the difference between namespace and use, I can't understand it, I thought use with 'AS' is for making a shortcut for a namespace

i thought for using use without for namespace you have to include/require something, but this example in the screenshot just confuses me

[Screenshot from 7:11 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLFNVXY0APk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCpuP.png)

Comment: A namespace is like a container, a use statement is like including another container inside the one you are in.  It's a method to prevent naming conflicts if for example 2 classes have the same name, if the namespace is different everything is cool.  Importing( include/require) is a whole other topic.

Comment: `namespace` is like "This class lives here." `use` is like "Get me a class that lives somewhere else."

Comment: With AS it is a shortcut to a namespace, without it if It includes the class name, then its a shortcut to the class....

Answer (score 0):

In PHP a namespace is a container that encapsulates some "stuff": functions classes, interfaces or traits.  It's done to avoid naming conflicts, because in PHP (or most languages) you can only declare a class/function/interface/trait one time and one time only.

So for example, you could have a class named `Users` and another class called `MyProject\Users` because the second has a namespace this prevents conflict with the first.  Otherwise (without the namespace) it would be ambiguous which one you wanted and so PHP will give an error if you try it.

A Use statement allows you to Use a namespace without referring to the whole thing.  If you are in the global or base namespace these 2 things are roughly equivalent

```
 new \MyProject\Users();
```

AND

```
use MyProject\Users
new Users();
```

The big advantage to the second one is if you decide to change the namespace, you only have to change it in the Use statement and not every class call within the namespace.  Beyond that it's much less to type, and we programmers don't like to type if we don't have to.

Now as for the AS keyword, you can use this to resolve conflits, or to just shorten namespaces for example:

```
 use MyProject as M; //now M = MyProject 

 new M\Users(); // MyProject user class
 new Users(); //base namespace user class
```

This really has nothing to do with how you import the code into PHP, however there are some naming conventions (like PSR4) that deal with properly placing files according to their namespace. But that doesn't change depending how you make use of `Use`.  The general "rule of thumb" is that the namespace should match the directory structure, that way we can make use of auto loaders as opposed to including every file at the beginning.  Autoloaders only load the class file when it's needed, and as I said this is based of properly naming and namespacing the class and directory structure.

I hope that makes sense.